# Error in reading string from file

Tags: c

I am having some trouble with reading a string from another file and storing it to an array. I need a pointer to point to that array so I can use it throughout the program. All variables are global. Please help fix the fgets lines to work with this. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void load_data();

int value;

char name[25];
char * nameP = NULL;

char another_name[25];
char * another_nameP = NULL;

int main()
{
   load_data();

   printf("value = %i\n", value);
   printf("name = %s\n", name);
   printf("another name = %s\n", another_name);

   return 0;
}
void load_data()
{
   FILE * fileP;

   if (!(fileP = fopen ("save_file.dat", "rt")))
   {
      printf("\nSave file \"save_file.dat\" not found.\n");
      printf("Make sure the file is located in the same folder as the executable file.\n\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   rewind(fileP);
   fscanf (fileP, "%i", &value);
   fgets (name, 25, fileP); // what is wrong with this line?
   fgets (another_name, 25, fileP); // what is wrong with this line?

   nameP = name;
   another_nameP = another_name;
}
```

Contents of save_file.dat:

```
30
This is my name
This is another name
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it perhaps because your `fscanf` doesn't include the `\n` character? Try:

```
fscanf(fileP, "%i\n", &value);
```

Since you don't read the new line character, your `fgets` (on the next line) simply continues reading until it finds either an `EOF` or `\n`. In this case, it instantly finds a `\n` character, so it stops reading. Hence, the 3rd line of your file is never being read.

---

In order to remove new lines at the end of `fgets`, simply add a function to do so:

```
void remove_newline(char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (str[len-1] == '\n') {
        str[len-1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Remember to `#include <string.h>`. Then, before printing out the data, simply call:

```
remove_newline(name);
/* ... */
printf("name = %s\n", name);
```

Comment: I suspect that might be true given the type of output I have been getting. But adding the '/n' won't included it the string or value will it? I guess I will have to wait until I am home to test it.

Comment: No, it won't. If you place a `\n` in the `fscanf` function, it will only read an integer, followed by a new line.

Comment: It reads the integer fine but when it comes to fgets it reads the \n into name. I need it to read just the characters up to the \n.

Comment: Sure, I think you'll have to remove the new line manually. Have a look at my updated answer.